# How to convert an OpenGL ES texture into a CIImage

Tags: opengl-es, ios5, opengl-es-2.0, core-image, core-video

I know how to do it the other way around. But how can I create a CIImage from a texture, without having to copy into CPU memory? [CIImage imageWithData]? CVOpenGLESTextureCache?

Comment: Just an update for iOS 6, this is now possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think there's any way to avoid having to read back pixel data using `glReadPixels()`. All of the inputs for a CIImage (data, CGImageRef, CVPixelBufferRef) are CPU-side, so I don't see a fast path to deliver that to a CIImage. It looks like your best alternative there would be to use `glReadPixels()` to pull in the raw RGBA data from your texture and send it into the CIImage using `-initWithData:options:` and an `kCIFormatRGBA8` pixel format. (Update: 3/14/2012) On iOS 5.0, there is now a faster way to grab OpenGL ES frame data, using the new texture caches. I describe this in detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9704392/19679).

However, there might be another way to achieve what you want. If you simply want to apply filters on a texture for output to the screen, you might be able to use [my GPUImage framework](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) to do the processing. It already uses OpenGL ES 2.0 as the core of its rendering pipeline, with textures as the way that frames of images or video are passed from one filter to the next. It's also much faster than Core Image, in my benchmarks.

You can supply your texture as an input here, so that it never has to touch the CPU. I don't have a stock class for grabbing raw textures from OpenGL ES yet, but you can modify the code for one of the existing GPUImageOutput subclasses to use this as a source fairly easily. You can then chain filters on to that, and direct the output to the screen or to a still image. At some point, I'll add a class for this kind of data source, but the project's still fairly new.

Comment: Thanks, Brad. Have you worked with CVOpenGLESTextureCache? It seems that should be the alternative to glReadPixels, if there's no other way. There is a method just for my question on OS X, and it seems there must be a way due to how Apple is focusing on GPUs...

Comment: @akaru - Unless I'm missing something, CVOpenGLESTextureCache is just for the unidirectional upload of textures in a fast manner. I don't think that it can be used for reading anything back from an OpenGL ES texture. I've not seen any reference to doing this in the headers or Apple's presentations on the topic. I think we're stuck with `glReadPixels()` on iOS.

Comment: @akaru - I can't find your earlier question about this, but it turns out I was wrong about the texture caches being unidirectional. I just got them working to encode video, and they are way faster than `glReadPixels()`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9704392/19679

Answer (score 3):

As of iOS 6, you can use a built-in init method for this situation:

```
initWithTexture:size:flipped:colorSpace:
```

See the docs: 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

You might find these helpful:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/RosyWriter/Introduction/Intro.html
- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLCameraRipple/Listings/GLCameraRipple_RippleViewController_m.html

In general I think the image data will need to be copied from the GPU to the CPU. However the iOS features mentioned above might make this easier and more efficient.