# glReadPixels alternative

Tags: ios, opengl-es, rendering

I want to screen capture iOS frames into an `AVAssetWriter` (or even just a `UIImage`). The traditional method of using `glReadPixels` works just fine - but very slow. I understand that since iOS 5.0 I can use a different - faster, method.
I followed lots of posts, like : [OpenGL ES 2d rendering into image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455329/opengl-es-2d-rendering-into-image/10455622#10455622) 
which mention the use of `CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreate` - but can't get it to work.

Right now, right before every call to presentRenderbuffer: - I'm following apple's sample with `glReadPixels` (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1704/_index.html) which works. When trying to follow this post - [OpenGL ES 2d rendering into image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455329/opengl-es-2d-rendering-into-image/10455622#10455622) to get the image, which basically replaces the call to glReadPixels with creating a cache texture, and binding it to a render target (a pixel buffer), and then read from the pixel buffer - it seems to "steal" the images from the screen - so nothing is rendered.

Can anyone shed some light on how to do this? Also, please mention if this works only for OpenGL ES 2.0 - I am looking for a fast alternative which will work also on previous versions.

A code sample would be excellent.

Comment: You aren't trying to present your texture-backed FBO to the screen, are you? You're probably going to want to render to your texture, grab the bytes from the associated pixel buffer, then re-render the texture to the screen via a quad and a passthrough shader.

Comment: Thanks, can you add some code samples for the entire process ? I'm kind of new to OpenGL (as mentioned, the starting point is presentRenderbuffer: - which my current code reads the frame buffer using glReadPixels)

Thanks!