# Screen Capture of Graphics Drawn to GPU?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, opengl-es

I have the following code which I use to capture the contents of a view into an image:

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.mainView.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
}
else
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.mainView.bounds.size);
}

[self.mainView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *image = [UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() retain];
```

Recently, I tried attaching a `GLKView` (which I use to apply Core Image filters in real time on the GPU) to the `mainView`. When I execute the above code, it doesn't capture the graphics in the `GLKView` (instead basically just ignores it).

So my question is, is it possible to capture graphics to an image that are drawn on the GPU and haven't yet been copied back to the CPU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to grab the view's framebuffer pixel data using OpenGL ES.  You can't do it with `renderInContext:`.

There are a couple of ways to use OpenGL ES to grab the data.  Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10455622/77567) for details.