# Fast Screen Recording of iOS App

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, core-video

I'm new to OpenGL ES. 
I'm trying to write code for screen recording of iOS apps, especially games.

I'm using the 'render to texture' method described with code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9704392/707773) to capture screen and write the video for a cocos2d game.
One modification I made was that, when I call `CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreate` then I'm using
`[EAGLContext currentContext]`
instead of

`[[GPUImageOpenGLESContext sharedImageProcessingOpenGLESContext] context]`

It does record the video but there are two issues

(1)- When it starts recording then new drawing on the screen stops. I want the app to keep on drawing on the screen too. As I'm new to OpenGL ES, I don't have deep understanding of frame buffer objects etc., so I have a hard time figuring out how to simultaneously draw on screen and capture the screen as well. I'll appreciate a code example in this regard.

(2)- The recorded video is flipped upside down. How can I get it in correct direction?

Previously I considered `glReadPixels` method too, but that has performance drawbacks.

Update: a couple of  ideas also came to mind. According to my little understanding,

I could simply draw my texture back to screen, but don't know how.

OR

I could have a secondary FBO and I could attach the texture to it, i.e.

```
glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &textureFrameBuffer);
glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, textureFrameBuffer);

glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(renderTexture), 0);
//Then I restore the screen FBO.
glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, 1);
```

But if I do that, then how do I copy the screen-drawing to my secondary FBO?

Comment: Is your problem solved? I am still facing the same issue but instead of cocos2d I am using Sparrow framework?

Answer (score 0):

There are readymade solutions for this, so if you're not looking to re-invent the wheel, you can try out Everyplay (https://everyplay.com/about).

The documentation for recording the screen from the OpenGL level can be found here: https://developers.everyplay.com/doc/Everyplay-integration-to-iOS-game

Disclaimer: I work for the company that makes Everyplay

Comment: Thanks TuomasR, however the nature of my app requires somewhat reinvention of this wheel. :), I'll highly appreciate if you could throw in a few lines of code or direct me on how to copy rendered image from one FBO to another. Many thanks.