# Migrating from glReadPixels to CVOpenGLESTextureCache

Tags: ios, opengl, opengl-es-2.0, glkit, core-video

Curretly, I use glReadPixels in an iPad app to save the contents of an OpenGL texture in a frame buffer, which is terribly slow. The texture has a size of 1024x768, and I plan on supporting Retina display at 2048x1536. The data retrieved is saved in a file.

After reading from several sources, using CVOpenGLESTextureCache seems to be the only faster alternative. However, I could not find any guide or documentation as a good starting point.

How do I rewrite my code so it uses CVOpenGLESTextureCache? What parts of the code need to be rewritten? Using third-party libraries is not a preferred option unless there is already documentation on how to do this.

Code follows below:

```
//Generate a framebuffer for drawing to the texture
glGenFramebuffers(1, &textureFramebuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, textureFramebuffer);

//Create the texture itself 
glGenTextures(1, &drawingTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, drawingTexture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F_EXT,  pixelWidth, pixelHeight, 0, GL_RGBA32F_EXT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

//When drawing to or reading the texture, change the active buffer like that:
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, textureFramebuffer);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId, 0);

//When the data of the texture needs to be retrieved, use glReadPixels:
GLubyte *buffer = (GLubyte *) malloc(pixelWidth * pixelHeight * 4);
glReadPixels(0, 0, pixelWidth, pixelHeight, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid *)buffer);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Faster alternative to glReadPixels in iPhone OpenGL ES 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550297/faster-alternative-to-glreadpixels-in-iphone-opengl-es-2-0)

Comment: Unfortunately, the app I develop is about drawing, and this is too much video-oriented. I am looking for an approach with as little refactoring as possible.