# Creating an RGB CVOpenGLESTexture in iOS

Tags: ios, textures, opengl-es-2.0, core-video

I am trying to create a **3-channel** `CVOpenGLESTexture` in iOS.

I can successfully create a **single-channel** texture by specifying `kCVPixelFormatType_OneComponent8` in `CVPixelBufferCreate()` and `GL_LUMINANCE` for both `format` and `internalFormat` in `CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage()`.

Similarly, I can successfully create a **4-channel** RGBA texture by specifying `kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA` in `CVPixelBufferCreate()` and `GL_RGBA` for both `format` and `internalFormat` in `CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage()`.

I need to create **3-channel**, 24-bit, RGB (or BGR) texture with accessible pixels.
I cannot seem to find the correct parameters (or combination thereof) to `CVPixelBufferCreate()` and `CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage()` that will not cause either of them to fail.

**Additional Info**
The supported FOURCC format types [reported](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1501/_index.html) by `CVPixelFormatDescriptionArrayCreateWithAllPixelFormatTypes()` on my device:
`32`, **`24`**, `16`, `L565`, `5551`, `L555`, `2vuy`, `2vuf`, `yuvs`, `yuvf`, `40`, **`L008`**, `L010`, `2C08`, `r408`, `v408`, `y408`, `y416`, **`BGRA`**, `b64a`, `b48r`, `b32a`, `b16g`, `R10k`, `v308`, `v216`, `v210`, `v410`, `r4fl`, `grb4`, `rgg4`, `bgg4`, `gbr4`, `420v`, `420f`, `411v`, `411f`, `422v`, `422f`, `444v`, `444f`, `y420`, `f420`, `a2vy`, `L00h`, `L00f`, `2C0h`, `2C0f`, `RGhA`, `RGfA`, `w30r`, `w40a`, `w40m`, `x420`, `x422`, `x444`, `x44p`, `xf20`, `xf22`, `xf44`, `xf4p`, `x22p`, `xf2p`, `b3a8`.

Interestingly, some of these values are not defined in `CVPixelBuffer.h`.

When I pass `kCVPixelFormatType_24RGB` (`24 == 0x18`) to `CVPixelBufferCreate()` it succeeds, but then `CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage()` fails with [error code -6683](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1781/_index.html):`kCVReturnPixelBufferNotOpenGLCompatible`.

Answer (score 2):

Answering myself, though I will be happy to be proved wrong and shown how to do this.

As I show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27149380/how-to-list-all-opengl-es-compatible-pixelbuffer-formats/27152363#27152363) (answering myself yet again) it is possible to list all the fourCC buffer formats supported on the device, and a bunch of format attributes associated with each such fourCC format.

The flags pertinent to this question are:

- `kCVPixelFormatOpenGLESCompatibility`
- `kCVPixelFormatContainsAlpha` : Should be false;
- `kCVPixelFormatContainsRGB` : Note: supported only from `__IPHONE_8_0`, but not strictly necessary;
- Using the debugger, I found another helpful key: `CFSTR("IOSurfaceOpenGLESTextureCompatibility")` which will verify that the OpenGL ES texture supports direct pixel access with no need for (the slower) `glReadPixels()` and `glTexImage2D()`.

Unfortunately, using these flags, it seems that there is currently no such RGB/BGR supported format.