# How to List all OpenGL ES Compatible PixelBuffer Formats

Tags: ios, core-video

Is there a way to list all `CVPixelBuffer` formats for `CVPixelBufferCreate()` that will not generate error `-6683: kCVReturnPixelBufferNotOpenGLCompatible` when used with `CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage()`?

[This](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1501/_index.html) lists *all* the supported `CVPixelBuffer` formats for `CVPixelBufferCreate()`, but does not guarantee that `CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage()` will not return the error above.
I guess my desired list should be a subset of this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [the answer from Adi Shavit above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27152363), here's a full code snippet (Objective-C) that you can use to print all the current OpenGL ES compatible pixel formats:

```
+ (void)load {
  @autoreleasepool {
    printf("Core Video Supported Pixel Format Types:\n");

    CFArrayRef pixelFormatDescriptionsArray = CVPixelFormatDescriptionArrayCreateWithAllPixelFormatTypes(kCFAllocatorDefault);
    for (CFIndex i = 0; i < CFArrayGetCount(pixelFormatDescriptionsArray); i++) {
      CFNumberRef pixelFormatFourCC = (CFNumberRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(pixelFormatDescriptionsArray, i);

      if (pixelFormatFourCC != NULL) {
        UInt32 value;

        CFNumberGetValue(pixelFormatFourCC, kCFNumberSInt32Type, &value);

        NSString * pixelFormat;
        if (value <= 0x28) {
          pixelFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Core Video Pixel Format Type 0x%02x", (unsigned int)value];
        } else {
          pixelFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Core Video Pixel Format Type (FourCC) %c%c%c%c", (char)(value >> 24), (char)(value >> 16), (char)(value >> 8), (char)value];
        }

        CFDictionaryRef desc =  CVPixelFormatDescriptionCreateWithPixelFormatType(kCFAllocatorDefault, (OSType)value);
        CFBooleanRef OpenGLESCompatibility = (CFBooleanRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(desc, kCVPixelFormatOpenGLESCompatibility);
        printf("%s: Compatible with OpenGL ES: %s\n", pixelFormat.UTF8String, (OpenGLESCompatibility != nil && CFBooleanGetValue(OpenGLESCompatibility)) ? "YES" : "NO");
      }
    }

    printf("End Core Video Supported Pixel Format Types.\n");
  }
}
```

You can put this snippet anywhere in a Objective-C category or class to print which pixel format are compatible and which aren't.
For completeness purposes, here are all the pixel formats currently compatible with OpenGL ES as of iOS 10.2.1:

- `L565`
- `5551`
- `L555`
- `2vuy`
- `yuvs`
- `yuvf`
- `L008`
- `L016`
- `2C08`
- `2C16`
- `BGRA`
- `420v`
- `420f`
- `420e`
- `411v`
- `411f`
- `422v`
- `422f`
- `444v`
- `444f`
- `L00h`
- `L00f`
- `2C0h`
- `2C0f`
- `RGhA`
- `RGfA`

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself...  after further study of [this link.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1501/_index.html)
The function `CVPixelFormatDescriptionArrayCreateWithAllPixelFormatTypes()` provides all the supported formats on a particular device (and OS). Once the fourCC value is found as shown in the [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1501/_index.html), you can use `CVPixelFormatDescriptionCreateWithPixelFormatType()` to get a dictionary with various fields describing each format.

This looks something like this:

```
UInt32 value;
CFNumberGetValue(pixelFormatFourCC, kCFNumberSInt32Type, &value);
auto desc =  CVPixelFormatDescriptionCreateWithPixelFormatType(kCFAllocatorDefault, (OSType)value);
auto OpenGLCompatibility = (CFBooleanRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(desc, kCVPixelFormatOpenGLCompatibility);
auto OpenGLESCompatibility = (CFBooleanRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(desc, kCVPixelFormatOpenGLESCompatibility);
```

If `OpenGLESCompatibility` is true then this format is OpenGL ES compatible.