# Draw to an offscreen renderbuffer in OpenGL ES 3 IOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, gpu

Is there a way to get back to a CVPixelBuffer after running the GPU so a program can process it for networking?

Comment: What about [glReadPixels](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glReadPixels.xhtml)

Comment: My answer here describes a fast process for doing this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550297/faster-alternative-to-glreadpixels-in-iphone-opengl-es-2-0